# Debugging the JNI Source code in visual studio 2003 without using eclipse?

Tags: java, c, debugging, java-native-interface

In visual studio 2003's project settings, I specified the java.exe as the program to execute when debugging. I set the working directory in which the JNI dlland JNI jar is available.

I set the class paths and the command line arguments which I would pass to java in the program arguments.

The java file which I am using is compiled with the JNI jar file. In the java file I am trying to connect to a particualr driver using the following code. Driver d = (Driver)Class.forName(drivername).newInstance();

// GET CONNECTION con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,user,password);

When running the java file in Visual studio I get the error "driver name not found".The visual studio not loading the jar file properly. How to resolve this problem without using eclipse?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a classpath problem, not a JNI problem.

Eclipse builds up a classpath for you, from the libraries/projects that you specify in the build path. When you're running from Visual Studio, you'll have to create that classpath yourself. Assuming that you can pass command-line arguments when you start `java.exe` from Visual Studio, add the `-cp` argument as described here: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

Comment: And if it does turn out to be a classpath problem, please edit your question and tags appropriately.